# Making parent methods return child instance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtfs

I would like to overwrite a class (*Feed*) from [gtfs-kit](https://github.com/mrcagney/gtfs_kit) with my own *Feed* class keeping original methods and adding my own. The problem is: when I call a method from the original class from an instance of my class that return the instance, it return an instance of the parent class instead.

My class definition:

```
import gtfs_kit as gk

class Feed(gk.feed.Feed):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Original class: https://github.com/mrcagney/gtfs_kit/blob/master/gtfs_kit/feed.py

An example:

```
import gtfs_kit as gk
from .gtfs import Feed

# Reading a GTFS feed with GTFS-Kit
data_folder = 'data/'
feed = gk.read_feed(data_folder +'gtfs.zip', dist_units='km') # feed is <gtfs_kit.feed.Feed>

# Convert in my own feed class
feed_dict = {table: getattr(feed, table) for table in gk.cs.GTFS_REF["table"]} 
feed_dict['dist_units'] = feed.dist_units
feed = Feed(**feed_dict) # feed is <gtfs.Feed>

# Calling a GTFS-kit method
feed = feed.append_dist_to_shapes() # Feed returns to <gtfs_kit.feed.Feed>
```

I would like this method and all other similar methods to return my instance of my own *Feed* class.

Any suggestion ?

(Btw, it's my first Stack post. Any constructive comment on the format is appreciated)

Comment: Unless `read_feed()` has a parameter telling it what class to create, I don't think there's an easy way to accomplish this. Are you sure you need a subclass rather than just referencing the feed object as an attribute of your class?

Comment: This would be an option.

I know that what i'm looking for is possible. I've seen similar implementation with GTFS-Kit, but I don't understand the difference with my solution.

Comment: It looks like you just need to override the [`copy`](https://github.com/mrcagney/gtfs_kit/blob/3a4f5dc576be5f332cae5bb9b665b9ad1d72ae3d/gtfs_kit/feed.py#L320) method, and return an object of your own class instead

Comment: Glad it worked. Be careful relying too much on the current implementation of this library, as the author [states](https://github.com/mrcagney/gtfs_kit#notes=) it is still in alpha and may change without much warning